# How to write a multi-step registration form in one page?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I want to make a multi step registration form. When user enters his name it, it checks in the database whether that username exists or not, then it should go to 2nd step where he will enter new password and once submitted for that username an OTP will be sent to registered mobile number.

In 3rd step OTP confirm page should open and on giving correct entry the process should be completed. I have written a basic code to achieve this, but I want it to happen step by step, in one page itself.

Comment: use AJAX to check the database

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality you have to work with ajax

for example when user enter username you can post request like this

.JS file

```
var username = $('#username_textfield_id').val();
$post('ajax.php',
    {data:username}
).success(function(responce){
    if(responce == 'available')
        $('#password_field').css({display:'block'}); // password field will be hidden by default
    else
        alert(responce);
});
```

You can call above function on focus out of text field or you can put button. :-)

ajax.php file

```
<?php
     $username = $_POST['data'];
     /* check username in database */ 
     if(username available )
        echo "available";
     else
        echo "username already taken";
?>
```

as per this files you can make steps in form.

you form will be something like this

`<input type="text" id="#username_textfield_id"> </br>
<input type="text" id="#password_field" style="display:none"></br>`

Answer (score -1):

make 4 small php files for each step. Each php should check if it is valid for rendering.

```
if(!user.hasEmail())
else if(user.hasEmail() & !user.haspassword())
  include php1
else if(user.haspassword() && !user.hasAddress())
  include php2
else if(user.hasAddress && !user.isconfirmed())
  include php3
```

Comment: If this is PHP, should `user` have a `$` prefix?

Comment: This is just a pseudocode.. Language syntax not covered. do as required please

Comment: You've not made it clear it is pseudocode in your answer, and fixing it would require minimal effort. -1, with apologies.